# SQLite MVVM return & obtain rowId in Activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mvvm, android-room

I have an app built using MVVM. I have the app successfully doing inserts into the SQLite database. I am now trying to obtain the rowId in the DB after the insert is done so on subsequent activities updates can be made to that row.

I fully understand the part where we change Void to Long in the DAO but I have no idea how to actually access that long at the activity level and save it into a variable that can be sent from activity to activity with Intent.PUTEXTRA. Code examples below.

Table / Entity Class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "CbtTable")
public class CbtTable {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long cbtId;
```

---

Repository class:

```
public class CbtRepository {

private CbtDao cbtDao;
private LiveData<List<CbtTable>> cbtData;
private FeelingFitDatabase mFeelingFitDatabase;

public CbtRepository(Application application) {
    mFeelingFitDatabase = FeelingFitDatabase.getInstance(application);
    cbtDao = mFeelingFitDatabase.getCbtDao();
    cbtData = cbtDao.getCbtData();
}


public void insertCbt(CbtTable cbtTable){

    new InsertCbtAsyncTask(cbtDao).execute(cbtTable);

}
```

---

DAO

```
@Dao
public interface CbtDao {

@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
public long insertAutoThought(CbtTable cbtTable);

@Query("UPDATE CbtTable SET automaticThought = :automaticThought WHERE cbtId = :cbtId")
void updateAutoThought(long cbtId, String automaticThought);

@Query ("UPDATE CbtTable SET twistedThinking = :twistedThinking WHERE cbtId = :cbtId")
void updateTwistedThinking(long cbtId, int twistedThinking);
```

---

ViewModel Class:

```
public class CbtViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private CbtRepository cbtRepository;
private LiveData<List<CbtTable>> cbtData;

public CbtViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    cbtRepository = new CbtRepository(application);
    cbtData = cbtRepository.getCbtData();
}

public void insert(CbtTable cbtTable){
    cbtRepository.insertCbt(cbtTable);
}

public void updateTwistedThinking(CbtTable cbtTable){
    cbtRepository.updateTwistedThinking(cbtTable);
}
```

---

Async task Class:

```
public class InsertCbtAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<CbtTable, Void, Void> {

private CbtDao mCbtDao;

public InsertCbtAsyncTask(CbtDao cbtDao){
    mCbtDao = cbtDao;
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(CbtTable... cbtTables) {
    mCbtDao.insertAutoThought(cbtTables[0]);
    return null;
}
```

---

Activity Method:

```
 private void saveAutomaticThought(){

    CbtTable cbtTable = new CbtTable(userId, automaticThoughtString, twistedThinking, challengeThoughtString, rationalThoughtString, postedWorkout);
    cbtViewModel.insert(cbtTable);
    long cbtId = cbtTable.getCbtId();

    // Sends the user to the WorkoutAutomaticThoughtActivity page
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WorkoutTwistedThinkingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("cbtId", cbtId);
```

With the above code in the **Activity** the cbtId is storing as 0 so it's not working. It's free of charge mental health app I'm developing to try and help people so the sooner I can resolve this the sooner I can get the app out there. I would greatly appreciate any help to debug this issue and get it working.

Comment: I'd really recommend you to stop using AsynTask. If you use that you can make that class receive a callback function and call it in onPostExecute. At the moment you're ignoring the result of mCbtDao.insertAutoThought. Just store that in a variable in your AsynTask class and use it later in the onPostExecute method.

Comment: Could you help me write the code for that? I'm a novice, I don't know how to structure the onPostExecute method to get the information I need and access it in the activity/fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend you to use AsynTask. But you can do something like this.

Make your InsertCbtAsyncTask accept a callback as parameter and call it after it has the inserted ID:

```
public class InsertCbtAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<CbtTable, Void, Void> {
    private CbtDao mCbtDao;
    private long id;
    private DoWithId callback;

    public InsertCbtAsyncTask(CbtDao cbtDao, DoWithId callback){
        mCbtDao = cbtDao;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(CbtTable... cbtTables) {
        id = mCbtDao.insertAutoThought(cbtTables[0]);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        callback.doWithId(id);
    }

    interface DoWithId {
        public void doWithId(long id);
    }

}
```

Then, when calling that class you can pass the callback as parameter. For example:

```
    DoWithId callback = new DoWithId() {
        @Override
        public void doWithId(long id) {
            launchIntentWithId(id)
        }
    };
    new InsertCbtAsyncTask(cbtDao, callback).execute(cbtTable);
```

`launchIntentWithId()` would look like this:

```
public launchIntentWithId(long cbtId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WorkoutTwistedThinkingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("cbtId", cbtId);
    startActivity(Intent);
}
```

This code is not tested and may not be complete but it should give you a complete idea.

Comment: Thanks for helping with the code. I was following all of it up until the last method. The launchIntentWithId Method. Where is that method placed? It can't be placed in the respository along with the execute code as it doesnt recognise commands like startActivity as its not an activity or fragment. The repository is just a POJO.

Comment: It has to be placed somewhere startActivity can be called, like the Activity, below saveAutomaticThought(). And saveAutomaticThought() can call that AsynTask.

Comment: Nah unfortunately this doesnt work because the method call launchIntentWithId(id) isnt recognised because that method is in a different class / activity. To call it I have to instantiate the class to call the method which means there is no data in any of the variables because its newly instantiated so it just throws a lot of null pointers

Comment: Just place the method where you need it to be. Try to understand the logic. Don't just copy the code.

Comment: I was able to get this working by building on the answer you provided. Thank you very much for your guidance. I really appreciate it.